# Edward Snowden has been in 'transit' in Moscow for days now. What's the longest possible you can just stay in a terminal?

Tags: transit, international-travel, airports, airport-terminals

If Putin and others are to be believed, Edward Snowden has been airside in transit in Moscow's Sheremetyevo airport for close on a week now.  Is there an international 'record' that anyone's done not being 'in a country' - but just airside in a terminal?

(The Tom Hank movie comes to mind, but I've no idea how much of that was accurate)

Comment: Allegedly he can legally be there only 24-hours, as the airport's website states: *"foreign citizens can stay in Sheremetyevo airport for up to 24 hours without a Russian visa"*.

Comment: @vartec I guess at some point they'll infer whether or not the Novotel hotel attached with its special 'transit' area counts or not :/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's [a good article to answer your question on the Washington Post website](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/worldviews/wp/2013/06/26/heres-what-happens-to-asylum-seekers-who-stay-in-airport-limbo-indefinitely/?tid=rssfeed):

> All those jokes comparing Snowden’s case to the Tom Hanks film “The Terminal”? They have a distinctly unromantic basis in the life of Iranian [Mehran Karimi Nasseri](http://www.csmonitor.com/2004/0621/p11s02-almo.html), who lived in Paris’ Charles de Gaulle Airport for **18 years** after Iran expelled him.