# Can I take my battery backup/energizer/secondary power source in flight?

Tags: air-travel, electronic-items, hand-luggage

I have bought one battery backup/energizer/secondary power source (2500 mAh). I am going to India this week but not sure whether I can carry battery backup on flight. The website of Air Canada does not specify whether a battery backup is allowed on flight.

To make it more clear for you I have attached the images:

[image: Battery Backup]
[image: Battery Backup]

Comment: What is a "battery energizer"? Around here "Energizer" is a brand name for non-rechargeable batteries. Do you mean a charger for rechargeable batteries? Or (guessing wildly) an UPS?

Comment: It is like a battery backup which you can use to charge your mobile or tablet.

Comment: You can charge it using the mobile charger and use it during long traveling   for your mobile/tab charging.

Comment: What kind of battery is in it? If it's a lithium battery, most airlines have rules based on the capacity in Wh -- your measurement in mAh doesn't immediately make sense in this context, unless accompanied by a voltage specification.

Comment: The output voltage by device is 5 volt 1 A  and 5V/2.1A. It has  Li-ion polymer cell.

Comment: Some countries/airports only seem to allow the batteries if they have their power as part of the information that is on the item.

Comment: These items are sold at the tax free shops in airports, so you would not expect problems.

Comment: See also: [How to calculate if my battery will be allowed in hand luggage? (Voltage in mAh to Wh conversion)](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60055/how-to-calculate-if-my-battery-will-be-allowed-in-hand-luggage-voltage-in-mah). Can't believe this was closed as "unclear", that's ridiculous. Duplicate, maybe, but it's perfectly clear. 2,500 mAh is pretty small, I've travelled with 26,000 mAh bricks the size of a paperback novel and no-one has batted an eye, you'll almost certainly be fine.

Comment: Except it was closed 4 hours after the asker explained what these are using comments, two hours after a commenter had pointed out that these well-known items are commonly sold in airports, and an hour after Howdedo had linked to the duplicate. It's not "the community did not understand", it's a small harmful minority of up to five users failing to read comments.

Comment: @user568458 Comments are and always have been temporary, and it's perfectly valid for people to skip them. Indeed, some methods of viewing the site do not show the comments at all! Nothing relevant should _only_ be in a comment; everything should be edited in to the question.