# Do airlines really check whether battery packs for laptop/phone/tablets are less than 100 or 160 Wh?

Tags: airlines, airport-security, electronic-items, hand-luggage, batteries

From my understanding, the [International Air Transport Association (IATA) 
has some regulation regarding lithium-ion batteries that exceed 100 Wh](http://www.iata.org/whatwedo/cargo/dgr/Documents/lithium-battery-guidance-document-2015-en.pdf). In theory.

Do airlines really check whether battery packs for laptop/phone/tablets are less than 100 or 160 Wh?

I'm mostly interested in flights within the US as well as flights between US, France, and South Korea.

Examples of how these batteries look:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since you mention South Korea: There are some places where the regulations are even stricer, Hong Kong being one of them. So if you ever transfer there with the risk of going through security again, this is good to know. They check the mAh rating of the device (which must not be >=10000), and if there is none printed on it, they will keep it.

Comment: Since both the battery packs you're showing and also all regular laptop batteries are well below 100Wh: What kind of device do you have an issue with?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo E.g. [Poweradd™ Pilot Pro 32000mAh](http://www.amazon.com/Poweradd-Pilot-Pro-Multi-Voltage-Compatible/dp/B00DN0KBXU/ref=sr_1_2?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1434500758&sr=1-2&keywords=laptop+external+battery+pack&pebp=1434500763473&perid=0AC20TYVAK67HYC73PYF).

Comment: Just so you know, airlines never check luggage. Luggage is checked by customs and security personnel, but never airline staff.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I must definitely disagree.  I've had Chinese airport security catch a power bank I accidentally packed.   (It got left in my daypack rather than moved to the carry-on computer bag it was supposed to be in.)

Comment: Not sure how that disagrees with what I said.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No**, they don't.  Security looks for weapons and bombs; if it's not either, they're not interested.  Of course, there's always the off chance that you'll run into some particularly zealous *and* clued-in inspector with a fetish for lithium batteries, but realistically I wouldn't worry about it.

Also, 90% of the regulation you link to is about transporting lithium batteries in bulk as cargo, which they *are* concerned about since there have been [high-profile accidents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPS_Airlines_Flight_6) link to lithium battery fires in the cargo hold.

Answer (score 4):

In China, they are super strict about batteries and yes they read.  I haven't seen that much in the US, they seem to not be as strict.

Comment: Can you perhaps provide a link to back up your remarks?

Comment: @mdewey You'll probably find some mention of it in the China forum of Flyertalk.com.  Personally, I've seen them checking mine.

Comment: Also had my battery pack given a very close inspection at PEK everytime I've flown through there.

Comment: @mdewey https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/31083/1810

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention specifically South Korea, I just (2018/6/16) went through security at ICN, terminal 1. Here's what happened:

1. Check-in staff asked me whether I had batteries in my check-in luggage. Nope.
2. Trust but verify: I had to wait 5 minutes after check-in near the counters while my luggage was x-rayed.
3. I went through security. Staff opened my bag and visually inspected, among other things, my 16,000-mAh power bank. Which ain't that big.
   [image]

So the answer is your power bank will be inspected in Korea, but by airport security rather than the airline.

Comment: China, likewise.  They check them and seize anything oversize or unlabeled.