# Does any aviation authority / country have a limit lower than 100 watt hours (Wh) per lithium-ion battery in carry-on luggage?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, hand-luggage, electronic-items, batteries

My laptop has a 99.9WHr battery. [faa.gov](https://www.faa.gov/hazmat/packsafe/more_info/?hazmat=7#:%7E:text=Size%20limits%3A%20Lithium%20metal%20(non,person%20in%20their%20electronic%20devices.)) mentions:

> Size limits: Lithium metal (non-rechargeable) batteries are limited to 2 grams of lithium per battery. **Lithium ion (rechargeable) batteries are limited to a rating of 100 watt hours (Wh) per battery.** These limits allow for nearly all types of lithium batteries used by the average person in their electronic devices. With [airline approval](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/81938/1810), passengers may also carry up to two spare larger lithium ion batteries (101–160 Wh) or Lithium metal batteries (2-8 grams). This size covers the larger after-market extended-life laptop computer batteries and some larger batteries used in professional audio/visual equipment.

Does any aviation authority / country have a limit lower  than 100 watt hours (Whr) per lithium-ion battery in carry-on luggage?

I am aware that [checks](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/31083/1810) are [unlikely](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/49447/1810) in many airports but just to know ahead of time.