# Can a non-US citizen transit through Frankfurt Airport during COVID en route to the US?

Tags: usa, transit, germany, covid-19

I intend to travel from a non-Schengen country to the United States via air and transit through the Frankfurt Airport. I understand such transit does not require entry to the Schengen Zone, however the relevant [presidential proclamation](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/presidential-actions/2021/01/25/proclamation-on-the-suspension-of-entry-as-immigrants-and-non-immigrants-of-certain-additional-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of-transmitting-coronavirus-disease/) has

> noncitizens of the United States (“noncitizens”) who were physically present within the Schengen Area

And so this is not clear: the transit area is legally not part of the Schengen Zone but is it physically?

For example this [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/18565/4188) has

> Airport transit areas are exempted from immigration regulations, but they are very much the country's property, under its authority and jurisdiction.

Comment: I have completely rewritten the question to make the problem more clear and consequently deleted my incorrect answer.

Comment: What is your citizenship? What non-Schengen country are you coming from? How long have you been in that non-Schengen country?

Comment: Since the *Frankfurt Airport* is physically within the Schengen Area, when you are there you are ***physically* present within the Schengen Area**.

Answer (score 5):

#### No.

Transits through airports in countries that are on the list of bans for entry into the US count as physical presence there, so no, a non-exempt non-US citizen cannot currently travel to the US via Frankfurt or any other airport in the Schengen Area (and other countries similarly banned).

The [US Embassy in the Hague wrote](https://twitter.com/usembthehague/status/1273227033078890497?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1273227033078890497%7Ctwgr%5E%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.schengenvisainfo.com%2Fnews%2Fus-visa-esta-holders-outside-eu-cannot-transit-schengen-on-their-way-to-us%2F):

> Travelers with a U.S. #visa or valid #ESTA who are outside the EU are not permitted to #transit Schengen Area airports on their way to the U.S. Transiting the #Schengen Area subjects travelers to travel restrictions regardless of where their journey began.